# ElasticSearch NEST Reindex, edit name fields

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have an Index with nested Objects  something like

```
"_index": "originindex",
"_source": {
"message": "",
"environment": "",
"nestedObj": {
"field1": "field1",
"field2": 1 },
"anotherfield": 1}
```

And I want to reindexit to something like

```
"_index": "newindex",
"_source": {
"message": "",
"nestedObj-field1":"field1",
"nestedObj-field2": 1 ,
"anotherfield": 1}
```

I'am new to all of this I'm using Nest on .Net V4.5, it proposes a ReindexAPI But don'tknow how to use it for this purpose
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
POST _reindex
{
"source": {
  "index": "originindex"
},
"dest": {
  "index": "newindex"
},
"script":{
  "source":"ctx._source.nestedObj-field1 = ctx._source.remove(\"field1\");ctx._source.nestedObj-field2 = ctx._source.remove(\"field2\");"
}
```

Just make sure your mappings are in place on the dest index before you execute this.

Comment: Actually I know how to do it using POST _reindex, but i'm looking if it's possible to code it with Nest! Thakn you

Comment: @Neal I think I can get you that, but could your edit your question to provide the two associated types you would be using (assuming you're creating mappings form a model) ?

Comment: i insert dictionnaries not a specific model. the first time my dictionnary contain objects that's why i had nested objects in my doc but now i just insert simple datatype.